# Make box responsive in CSS

Tags: css, frontend, media-queries

I am trying to make the box responsive to scale with the mobile but it turns out it is very small when I resize the window.

Here is the HTML code:

```
            <div class="box">
                <h1>Health Status</h1>

                    <input type="text" id="check_infected" name="infected_check" placeholder="Infected by Corona? (Yes/No)">


                    <input type="submit" onclick="UpdateHealth();" value="Update">

                <div class="bottom-text">
                    We ensure to secure your health as well as the public health
                </div>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
.box{
    width: 30%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    background: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 812px) {
    .box{    
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 60px;
    }

  }
```

This is the image when it is not resized:
[image]

It turns out very small when it is resized:

[image]

How can I make the box scale with the screen or at least make the responsive box easier to see?

Comment: Where's the html ? You're expected to put up a working code snippet. Yet don't define a width, let the width be defined by the content.

Comment: I just updated the HTML code. How can I define width by content?

Answer (score 1):

**preliminary version: this anwser will need some updating depending on OP/any comment, so, please comment on errors, inconsistencies and omissions.**

## Intro

While the question is easy enough, 'how to scale a box to fit any device?', quite a few considerations need to be made. Instead of summing them up, I will use the images and code OP posted and take those to show how I came to my final version of the box (by approximation).

In any case, I will not be using several Media Queries when a single equation in a CSS **calc()**, can do the job just fine. Over the past few years I have learned to use a single equation ([*Codepen: responsive typography*](https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=responsive+typography), [*CSS-Tricks: Simplified Fluid Typography*](https://css-tricks.com/simplified-fluid-typography/) and [*Typekit blog: Flexible typography with CSS locks*](https://blog.typekit.com/2016/08/17/flexible-typography-with-css-locks/), to name a few examples) to calculate any CSS size-attribute value for any given browser viewport size, instead of using a list of MQs testing for specific viewport sizes ('breakpoints') and set specific size-attribute values.

The math is rather straighforward, **linear equation: y=mx+b**, which uses two known points on a straight line to calculate all other points on that line (check out *[MathIsFun: Equation of a Straight Line](https://www.mathsisfun.com/equation_of_line.html)*, easy to understand Middle School explanations, well worth the read).

**Pro**: Short code and works for any CSS size-attribute that accepts CSS **calc()**. Results in (much) less CSS, less maintenance.

**Con**: May take some more preparation when coding and only works for straight lines (no rocket science included) and exceptions to the CSS **calc()** result may still need some Media Query.

**tl;dr** - It is quite a lot of text, so here's the snippet first:

```css
/*
    All sizes in REM to honour browser user font settings (REM = size/16)
*/
.box {
    /*
        Going for approach 1. (Stackoverflow 61980111) to create the final box,
        we only need to define some smart padding.
        
        T/B (320,60)(1760, 30), y=-2.08vmin + 66.67
        L/R (320,30)(1760,100), y=4.87x + 14.45
    */
    padding: calc(-2.08vmin + 4.167rem) calc(4.87vmin + 0.9rem);
}
/* (320,14)(1280,20), y=0.00625x + 12 */
html  { font-size: calc(0.625vmin + 0.75rem) }
body  { font-size: 1rem }
input { font-size: 0.875rem; text-align: center }

/* (320,18)(1920,28), y=0.00625x + 16 */
h1    { font-size: calc(0.625vmin + 1rem); font-weight: normal }

/* Flexbox layout */
.wrapper, .box { display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; align-items: center }

.wrapper { height: 100% }

/**************************************/
/* Generally accepted preferred rules */
/**************************************/
html,body               { box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: 100% }
*::before,*::after, *   { box-sizing: inherit }
body                    { margin: 0 }

/******************/
/* eye-candy only */
/******************/
body {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.7); 
    background-image: linear-gradient(330deg, #e94974, #8073ab)
}
@media (orientation: portrait ) and (min-width : 50rem),
       (orientation: landscape) and (min-height: 50rem) { 
    body { background-image: linear-gradient(330deg, #3f96c8, #23c1bc) }
}

.box {
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;

    /* GMC elevation 3dp */
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.20),
                0px 3px 4px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.14),
                0px 1px 8px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}

input { margin-bottom: 1.5rem }

.pill {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;

    /* Flexbox Layout */
    display: inline-flex; 
    justify-content: center;
    align-content  : center;
    align-items    : center;

    /* Override default styling */
    padding: 0; border: none; outline: none; text-decoration: none;

    /* Sizing */
    width : 70%;
    height: calc(0.75vmin + 2.85rem); /* (320,48)(1920,60), y=0.75x + 45.6 */
    line-height: calc(0.75vmin + 2.85rem);

    /* Styling */
    opacity: .85;
    background-color: transparent; color: currentColor;

    border: 2px solid #ee7752;
    border-radius: calc((0.75vmin + 2.85rem)/2);
    /* IE has a problem with this and won't show rounded border, well known quirk! */

    /* Content not selectable */
    -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none;
    -moz-appearance: none; -webkit-appearance: none;

}
.pill:hover { opacity: 1 }

/* override default pill border color */
input[type="submit"].pill { border-color: #23a6d5 }

/* simulates button 'press' behaviour */
input[type="submit"]:active { transform: scale(.99) }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        <h1>HEALTH STATUS</h1>

        <input class="pill" type="text" id="check_infected" name="infected_check"
               placeholder="Infected by Corona? (Yes/No)"
               onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"
               onblur="this.placeholder = 'Infected by Corona? (Yes/No)'">

        <input class="pill" type="submit" onclick="UpdateHealth();" value="Update">

        <p class="bottom-text">We ensure to secure your health as well as the public health</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**So, what do we know?** (derived from OP posted images and code)

- viewport: 861x1883 (blue image size), ratio 2.18699
- box: 505x877 (measured in image)

  - height 58.66% and width 46.58% in landscape mode (OP defined width: 30%)
  - ratio 1883/861 ~ 1.736633, close to either 17:10 (1.7) or 16:9 (1.78)
  - or stick to 1.736633
- padding: 30px 100px, large devices (defined in CSS)
- padding: 30px  60px, small devices (between 375px and 812px)
- We cannot simply use a single percentage for box W/H and padding because of the different height/width ratios of mobiles vs tablets vs desktops.
- Mobile OS'es have their own style of presenting modals:

  - floating on top of the main app with some (narrow) margin
  - or they go full screen
- Are we going to mimic mobile behaviour or define our own style?

Check **statcounter** to get background info on current device resolutions to determine possible W/H and ratio for our box:

- [mobile](https://gs.statcounter.com/screen-resolution-stats/mobile/worldwide) (1.78 or 2.16, 360x640, 414x896)
- [tablet](https://gs.statcounter.com/screen-resolution-stats/tablet/worldwide) (1.3 or 1.6, 768x1024, 800x1280)
- [desktop](https://gs.statcounter.com/screen-resolution-stats/desktop/worldwide) (1.78, 1366x768, 1920x1080)

## Approaches

There are various approaches to create the box the OP requires (in order of complexity, least complex first):

1. **Let the content determine the size of the box.** The more content, the taller the box grows. In this case we basically don't know the final size of the box and will need to create some (responsive) inner spacing taking the original height/width ratio into account.

   => box itself will not overflow (just grow), parent element might, depending on box content.
2. **Let the box's parent element (body or some wrapper) determine the size of the box.** This means that we need to manipulate the parent element inner space to create room for the box, as well as define some responsive inner box spacing.

   => either/neither box or parent may overflow depending on box content and overflow settings.
3. **Create a responsive sizing box by manipulating its height, width and inner spacing.** While the box size itself is responsive, its width and height are limited by the equation result. As with 2., some responsive inner box spacing has to be defined.

   => depending on content and spacing the box might overflow.

Given the layout, content and requirements by OP **we will be using approach 1.** For easy positioning of the box inside the viewport, as well as its content we will be using CSS 'flexbox layout'.

Check out CSS-tricks [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for a reference on FBL.

## The MATH

**using linear equation y=mx+b**

Envision an XY-graph with two points and a line drawn through those points, where

- **x-axis = viewport size in px** (either width or height of the browser window, parent element, device, etc.)
- **y-axis = size-attribute value in px** (any CSS attribute that accepts the use of CSS **calc()**, like font-size, width, height, padding, margin, top, left, bottom, right, etc.)

Those two points, **p1(x1,y1)** and **p2(x2,y2)**, depict a small size-attribute value on a small device and a large size-attribute value on a large device.

- **x1 =** minimum viewport size (mobile), **y1 =** minimum size-attribute value
- **x2 =** maximum viewport size (desktop), **y2 =** maximum size-attribute value

For example, in the snippet the equation for `html { font-size: calc(0.625vmin + 0.75rem) }` is derived by using points **p1(320,14)** and **p2(1280,20)**,

actually meaning: *p1 = 'minimum fontsize of 14px on a 320px screen'* and *p2 = 'maximum fontsize of 20px on a 1280px screen'*.

In this instance, we use **p1** and **p2** to calculate the box inner space (**padding**) by using either linear equation:

for CSS **calc()**

- *Y-intercept form*: **y = mx + b**
- CSS **`size-attribute: calc(m * x + b)`**

where

- **m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)**
- **x = is always 100vmin/vh/vw/vmax**, depends on size-attribute viewport W/H (in)dependency
- **b = y1 - m * x1**

alternatively use

- *point slope form*: **y = y1 + m(x - x1)**
- CSS **`size-attribute: calc(y1 * 1px + (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) * (x - x1 * 1px))`**, with **'m'** substituted and using **'* 1px'** to convert to pixel units, otherwise CSS **calc()** will fail.

*(Whichever fits your needs, where probably best is to manually calculate Y-INTERCEPT FORM variables **'m'** and **'b'** for use in calc(), less CPU intensive. POINT SLOPE FORM is great for use with CSS variables, SCSS and JS.)*

**Notes**

- for any CSS **calc()** used in the snippet, values for points **p1** and **p2** and the resulting equation are shown in `/* comments */`
- Set limits/constraints by using media queries. In case of element width and/or height attributes you can set their min-/max- counterparts.
- Use flexbox layout to center the box in the viewport.
- If you don't want to go full screen and use approach 3., determine a H:W ratio for any given device (best done in JS instead of @media), depends on device orientation. Using device ratios for you box makes the end result look better on a device.

*Make sure you 'own' this math, the sooner the better. With a few cleverly chosen minimums, maximums and simple calculations you can solve many responsiveness issues where you would otherwise need (vast) lists of Media Queries to accomplish the same result.*

***Please do pass the word as I think there are way too little developers using this technique for responsive design.***

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: your image width is 30% in your CSS code. When your screen is 1000px the image is normal with 300px but when you use a mobile phone with 320px screen the image is only 96px.

Answer (score 0):

In your media query, you are only defining a different `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`, but the rest of the settings stay the same as in the general CSS rule (for example `width: 30%`, which is probably the main problem).

You need to include and change every setting which you want to change in the media query, especially `width` and the paddings, similar to this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 812px) {
  .box{   
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    width: 80%;
    padding-left: 10%
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
  }

}
```